# Sintaxis [] y () no logro entender

Tags: python-3.x

Lo siguiente es una función que realiza el cifrado cesar:

```
def caesar(s, k, decode = False):
    trans = dict(zip(abc,abc[(k,26-k)[decode]:] + abc[:(k,26-k)[decode]]))
    return ''.join(trans[L] for L in s.upper() if L in abc)
```

La parte que se me complica es abc[(k,26-k)[decode]:] segun entiendo se trataria de un diccionario corrijanme si no es asi; a lo que voy es (k,26-k) que tipo de declaracion o lo que sea es esta?. Tambien quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre por poner un ejemplo entre [k:] y [:k].
Y perdon es que estoy empezando a aprender python.

Comment: si lo utilizas como empiezo para un algoritmo de encriptacion cesar
tiene varios fallos como que la palabra no puede tener  caracteres y solo permite 26 mayusculas y y no puedes utlizar una frase para encriptar!

Comment: No es el mejor algoritmo de Caesar para aprender Python, está muy ilegible para un principiante, adicional que da un error en la variable `abc` la cual no está definida en el ámbito de la función. Por otro lado, los slices pueden tener un [tercer argumento](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Este codigo lo habia sacado de internet y me llamo la atención la forma compacta en la que se implementa y quise aprender mas de el pero bueno tendre encuenta todo lo que mencionan.

Answer (score 4):

Respecto a la parte de la sintaxis `[k:]` y `[:k]` se refiere a un tema llamado "slicing" el cual te sirve para obtener secuencias o subarreglos de otro arreglo donde la notación es la siguiente:

```
arreglo[inicio:final:saltos]
```

Si tu no especificas el inicio, Python lo tomará desde la entrada 0, es decir

```
arreglo[:final:saltos] = arreglo[0:final:saltos]
```

Análogamente si no especificas el final, se interpretará que se hará el slicing hasta la última entrada, así como si no especificas los saltos, te recorrerá el arreglo de uno por uno, pero pondré un ejemplo para que se entienda. Recuerda nada más que para el inicio, la entrada que quieres, supongamos `k`, Python la toma como `k-1`, mientras que el final lo toma como `k`.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> l1[:]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> l1[2:]
[3,4,5,6]
>>> l1[:3]
[1,2,3]
>>> l1[2:5]
[3,4,5]
```

Comment: Excelente explicación crack gracias.