# que significa esta expresion str = str[1:] en python?

Tags: python

Tengo este codigo en Python pero no entiendo el significado de esta linea `str = str[1:]`
Les adjunto el codigo

```py
original = input("Escribe algo: ")

str = original
contador = 0

while str != "":
  str = str[1:]
  contador += 1

print("La cadena '{}' tiene {} caracteres".format(original, contador))
```

Comment: Eso se llama *slicing*, puedes pensar en esto como la función `sub_string` en otros lenguajes. Esto sirve para obtener parte del contenido de un iterable. En este caso lo que hace tu código es quedarse con la parte del string que va desde la posición 1 hasta el final, en otras palabras ignora el primer carácter. **observación**: estas sobrescribiendo la clase `str`, si luego intentas hacer algo como `print(str(10))` dará error

Comment: Aparte de que no deberias llamar `str` a una variable (pues `str` es un tipo de datos en python), hay formas mejores de calcular la longitud de una cadena, como por ejemplo `for c in cadena: contador+=1`. Sin contar que ni necesitas programar nada pues tienes `len(cadena)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Sintaxis \[\] y () no logro entender](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386789/sintaxis-y-no-logro-entender)